# Process for a rebellious wife?

Tags: marriage, money, sexuality, ketubah, maseches-kesubos

In the talmud the Rabbis discuss a "rebellious wife" who refuses to sleep with her husband. The husband is given recourse to deduct from her ketubah (marriage contract). This is discussed in tractate Ketubot Mishna 5:8. I would like to know if there is a process for this. Meaning does the husband file a formal complaint in court? Is this litigated? Can the wife contest? If there is no formal process does the husband just keep track and then at the time of payment display a list of deductions?

Comment: See Even HaEzer 77 for details. In short yes there is a formal litigation.

Comment: @DoubleAA i'm surprised that such public humiliation is sanctioned. was this process ever followed? it certainly doesn't seem to be today.

Comment: @rikitikitembonosarembocharibariruchipipperipembo On the other hand if the husband refuses intercourse then he violates a Biblical prohibition AND his monetary loss is unbounded. Her potential monetary loss is bounded (by the value of the Ketubah) and she doesn't violate a Biblical prohibition. Seems like he has the worse end of the deal. That said the Gemara in Ketubot does give reasons why her punishment is 'worse'.

Comment: @DoubleAA Does pinging with adding characters to the end of the username ping a user?

Comment: @Shokhet Not sure.

Comment: @Shokhetofchickensandquailbutnotpheasantsorpeacocksyet Did this ping you?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't believe it works, but shortening the name does work.